# How to update corresponding record with has_one association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a User model that **has_one** Bike and user **accepts_nested_attributes_for** a bike.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :bike

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bike
end
```

and

```
class Bike < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :profile
end
```

On my controller I pass bike's parameters like this:

```
params.require(:purchase).permit(bike_attributes: [:id, :type, :brand])
```

after that I am updating the current_user with the new info

```
def update
  current_user.update(purchase_params)
end
```

My problem is that with every new change for a current user, a new **bike** record gets created. For example If  I update the information about bike 10 times for the current user, then 10 bike records will be created and only the last one **Bike.last** will hold the right **user_id**.

How to prevent database from that and really update only one corresponding record?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the Bike is sending across the `id` attribute in the `params`. You should include a hidden `id` field for the bike if it's not currently there.